# no access to FB.Canvas.scrollTo with fluid height

Tags: facebook, canvas, fluid

You can access `FB.Canvas.getPageInfo` to read the information but they seem to be no way to scroll to a precise position in fluid height since `FB.Canvas.scrollTo` is only enabled when Canvas Height is set to "Settable (Default: 800px)" according to the [developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/).

Any idea why? Is there any workaround?

Comment: In this post you have some other ways to scroll your page.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480132/scrolling-facebook-canvas